I have ; in my URL and somehow wiremock is constructing it as %3B and the request is going wrongly
my URL is: https://aaaa.com/key=Fb75Q&amp;amp;client=login&amp;amp;tab=xVRQGWF08aY and wire mock is processing it as
Request URI:    http://localhost:9999/key=Fb75Q&amp%3Bclient=login&amp%3Btab=59FphpqxniY, Please help me, how to encode/decode the URL string to pass the correct delimiters
I tried with URLencode/decode but those are not working

If the URL is a string before wiremock's processing, I would not use &amp; within the string, but simply use & instead. Plus it looks like a ? is missing before key for the parameter string.
